# How to use frequencies in clojure to combine same frequency and display them once?

Tags: clojure

I making a poker hands game in clojure. I have to define a function such that such that it returns the ranks in the descending order. For example: order ["2H" "3S" "6C" "5D" "4D"] should return (6 5 4 3 2). But if there is a two-pair like this: ["5H" "AD" "5C" "7D" "AS"] then it should return (14 5 7), but mine returns [14 14 7 5 5], how can I correct this? It should work in the same way for other cases of poker hands as well like for a full house it should give the rank of the three of a kind and the rank of the two of a kind. So, for this I have written:

```
(defn order
                [hand]
                "Return a list of the ranks, sorted highest first"
                (let [ranks (reverse (sort (map #(.indexOf "--23456789TJQKA" %)
                                                (map #(str (first %)) hand))))]
                  (if (= ranks [14 5 4 3 2])
                    [5 4 3 2 1]
                    (into [] ranks))))
```

I have also written all the other poker hand functions like flush?, straight? etc.

Also, I have to define another function such that it takes two orders like '(8 5 9) '(8 7 3) and returns true if the first has the larger value of the first difference, else false. Could someone please give me an idea how to do this?

Comment: Let me see if I understand.  Are you asking how to remove duplicates from the sequence?

Comment: No. If you know poker hands then ["5H" "AD" "5C" "7D" "AS"] has two pairs i.e., two cards with same rank 5 and two cards with same rank A (which is read as 14). Now, by using my function, it displays: [ 14 14 7 5 5], because it sorts them, but I want it to display (14 5 7), that is, display 14 once, 5 before 7 because, 5H and 5C form a pair, so its rank would be higher than the single card 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to show sorting by count, then rank:

```
(defn ->r [hand]
  (let [ranks (zipmap "23456789TJKQA" (range 2 15)) ; creates a map like {\2 2, .... \A 14}
        count-then-rank
          (fn [x y] (compare 
                      [(second y) (first y)] 
                      [(second x) (first x)]))]
    (->> hand
         (map (comp ranks first)) ; returns the rank for each card eg: '(5 14 5 7 14)
         frequencies              ; returns a map of rank vs count eg: {5 2, 14 2, 7 1}
         (sort count-then-rank)   ; becomes a sorted list of tuples eg: '([14 2] [5 2] [7 1])
         (map first))))           ; extract the first value each time eg: '(14 5 7)
```

For a more complete solution, you can use the frequencies to determine if you have 4 of a kind, 3 of a kind, full house etc.

***Updated with more info on straight and straight flush:***

For a straight, one approach is:

1. Extract the ranks so you would have a list like '(14 3 2 4 5)
2. Sort this list to get '(2 3 4 5 14)
3. Get the first element: 2, and the last element 14
4. Construct a range from 2 (inclusive) to 15 (exclusive) to get '(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
5. Compare against the sorted sequence. In this case the result is false.
6. Retry, but first replace 14 with 1.

   - replace => '(1 3 2 4 5)
   - sort => '(1 2 3 4 5)
   - (range 1 6) => '(1 2 3 4 5)
   - This time, the range and the sorted list match, so this is a straight.

---

```
(defn straight? [cards]                             ; eg: ["AH" "3H" "2H" "4H" "5H"] 
  (let [ranks (zipmap "23456789TJKQA" (range 2 15))
        ranks-only (map (comp ranks first) cards)   ; eg: '(14 3 2 4 5)
        ace-high (sort ranks-only)                  ; eg: '(2 3 4 5 14)
        ace-low (sort (replace {14 1} ranks-only))  ; eg: '(1 2 3 4 5)
        consecutive #(= (range (first %) (inc (last %))) %)] ; eg: (= (range 1 6) '(1 2 3 4 5))
    (or (consecutive ace-high)
        (consecutive ace-low))))
```

For a flush, simply extract all the suits, and then ensure they are all equal:

```
(defn flush? [cards] 
    (apply = (map second cards)))  ; this is when suit is the second character
```

Now, simply combine these two boolean conditions to determine if this is a straight flush

```
(defn straight-flush? [cards]
     (and (straight? cards) (flush? cards)))
```

See if you can solve [4clojure best hand puzzle](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/178), to open up a large number of different ways to tackle this. When I solved this, I used similar, but not identical functions.

**Spoiler** a more complete solution (using suit first "D7" instead of rank first "7D") is below

> https://github.com/toolkit/4clojure-solutions/blob/master/src/puzzle_solutions/best_hand.clj

Comment: Hi, @toolkit: Your solution gives the result (5 14 7), it should give (14 5 7), right?

Comment: I am facing one issue now though, my previous function (the one that I wrote above) returned ( 5 4 3 2 1) when ["2H" "3H" "4H" "5H" "AH"] was given as input. Since, this is the case for straight flush, here value of A is considered as 1, and it should return (5 4 3 2 1), but your function returns (14 5 4 3 2).

Comment: @EricaMaine I would recommend creating a bunch of predicate functions, which you can then combine together as required. Eg: have functions for straight? flush? pair? three-of-a-kind? etc. I have a full solution if you don't want to figure it out yourself?

Comment: I tried adding (if (= ranks '(14 5 4 3 2))
     '(5 4 3 2 1)
   ranks)
for the example I mentioned, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know why. :O

Comment: Hi @toolkit, could you please explain your straight function? I mean I have a straight function in my code already. Where does this one go with regards to the r function?

Comment: I still could not understand where to add this condition for straight flush where A is a low ace, anyone willing to make me understand? :(

Comment: I already have all these functions in my code i.e. straight? straight-flush? flush? full-house? etc. My only point of concern is how to add the case where ace is low to the r function.

Comment: I guess I'm missing the issue. Having ace low only makes sense for the straight function, and doesn't need to be considered elsewhere. When counting frequencies to determine pairs, trips, 4-of-a-kind, Ace should always be considered high.

Comment: Exactly! My straight function which I have in the code is like this: (defn straight? "hand is straight?" [hand]
  (let [sorted-hand (hand-sort hand)]
    (and (= 5 (count (distinct sorted-hand)))
           (= 4 (- (first sorted-hand)
                   (last sorted-hand)))))) Even after adding your straight function with ace low, and then running the r function with ["2H" "3H" "4H" "5H" "AH"]  as input I'm still getting (14 5 4 3 2) as the output and not (5 4 3 2 1). This is my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`frequencies`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/frequencies) will get you closer to what you're looking for.

```
user=> (frequencies [14 14 7 5 5])
{14 2, 7 1, 5 2}
```

You could use this for [sorting](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sort-by):

```
user=> (sort-by (frequencies [14 14 7 5 5]) [14 14 7 5 5])
(7 14 14 5 5)
```

And then you could use [distinct](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/distinct):

```
user=> (distinct [14 14 7 5 5])
(14 7 5)
```

Putting all of these together should get you exactly what you want. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. When I'm stuck wondering if there's an easy way to do something, I often turn to [Clojure's cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet).

Comment: I tried your method too, why does it give (7 14 5) with that? It should be (14 5 7), right?

Comment: You want to *sort* the *distinct* elements of [14 14 7 5 5] by their rank, and then *sort by* *frequencies*, yes? :-)

Try:
(_____ (_______ [14 14 7 5 5]) (________ (_______ [14 14 7 5 5])))

And for a more rigorous solution, you could look into supplying a comparator for the sort. See the [examples on this page](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sort).